# Tomcat's thread pool plus custom thread pool in code of SpringBoot application

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

I've a Spring Boot application with Tomcat, and Tomcat has a default thread pool ( ~200). In my service I created an Executor with 10 fixed threads. Does it mean my application has 210 max thread pool?

Comment: No. It means you have a threadpool of 10 for use of other things than request handling.

Comment: Ok, if I watch threads in Visual VM, how many threads? 210? (suppose all threads are created)

Comment: That depends on the configuration, the threadpool can be dynamic (have a min/max) the same for Tomcat.